# C++ : Cookie not stored in one machine, but stored in another

Tags: c++, cookies, https, 64-bit, wininet

I am using a small C++ app that I wrote myself using VS 2010. 
This app accesses a website through HTTPS using these functions :

```
InternetOpen(), InternetConnect(), HttpOpenRequest(), HttpSendRequest(),
HttpQueryInfo(), InternetReadFile()
```

The app has been working fine for the last 2 years on a 32-bit machine running -initially- Win XP and currently Win 7 .
But it won't work on a 64-bit Win 7 machine, although it is still set to build 32-bit executable code  : the app fails to login to the website.

Checking with a HTTP traffic sniffer, I noticed that one request is done without the cookie set by the website.

My question is, where is the cookie stored normally ? As I said, I'm not using any library, only the aforementioned functions.

And what could be the reason for not storing the cookie in the second machine ?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: WinInet is the lib you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Managing Cookies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa385326%28VS.85%29.aspx) in MSDN. It explains that cookies live in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies\Low

I can't see any possible reason why the cookie mechanism could fail on x64. I'd rather expect that some local (IE) configuration option is in force that disables use of cookies for that site (e.g. the site being in a different zone, or the cookie being considered 3rd-party).

Comment: Weird, the 32-bit machine which runs the app smoothly has no "Cookies" folder in AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows... So I guess the cookie is saved somewhere else. I wonder if it could it be saved in the thread's memory..

Comment: Solved ! Indeed it was the IE settings that restricted use of cookies.

Comment: Cookies will most likely indeed be stored in the process memory (probably associated with the HINTERNET, on the heap) if they are session cookies (i.e. supposed to go away when the browser is closed, which probably matches InternetCloseHandle). Only persistent cookies should live on disk.